# Display images from SDcard into SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm trying to get an image from sd card using the intent

```
Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
       android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, 0);
```

by using this

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
    imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
chosenImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

`chosenImageView` referring to `ImageView` but whenever i try using `SurfaceView`, it doesn't given me the `.setImageBitmap`.

I know how to get an image over `imageView` but over `Surface` I find it kind of difficult to get the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `SurfaceView` you should create a static `ArrayList` or `Vector` to store your `Bitmap` and draw Bitmap in `onDraw`

```
public class Panle extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static ArrayList<Bitmap> mElements;
    private CanvasThread canvasThread;
    private Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public Panle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mElements = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        canvasThread = new CanvasThread(getHolder(), this);

        p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC));
        p.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        p.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, Blur.NORMAL));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (canvas != null)
            canvas.drawColor(0xffffffff);
        if (mElements != null && mElements.size() != 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i <= mElements.size() - 1; i++) {

                canvas.drawBitmap(mElements.get(i), 50, 50, p);// For example i fixed position at 50 50. You can change to another position

            }

        }

        super.draw(canvas);
    }
public static ArrayList<Bitmap> setmElements() {
    return mElements;
}

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (!canvasThread.isAlive()) {
            canvasThread = new CanvasThread(getHolder(), this);
            canvasThread.setRunning(true);
            canvasThread.start();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (canvasThread.isAlive()) {
            canvasThread.setRunning(false);
        }

    }

}
```

Now we need to handle the thread in our panel class.

```
public class CanvasThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private Panle _panel;
    private boolean _run = false;

    public CanvasThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Panle panel) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        _panel = panel;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }
    public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
        return _surfaceHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (_run) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {

                    _panel.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create panel in xml and get it in your activity. In order to draw image from `SDcard` using Intent to open Gallery, I use this to put retrieved image in onActivityForResult.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_GETTING_IMAGE) {

                if (data != null) {

                    Uri dataUri = data.getData();
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    bitmap = Utils.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(ImageUtil.getRealPathFromURI(CheDetailActivity.this, dataUri), Panel.getPanelW(), Panel.getPanelH());// I resize image from Gallery to avoid OOM
                    if (bitmap != null) {


                        Panel.getmElements().add(bitmap);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

You free to add any bitmap using `Panel.getElements.add(bitmap);`
Another tutorial you can see is [2D Tutorial Series](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-ii,772.html) which show very basic steps.

Comment: the example that you gave me is using the launcher icon as an image drawing over the surface , what i want is to get a picture from the user and display it over the surface as i'm going to use the android Effect media over the images.

Comment: My code is free to add any bitmap. I shown you example with pick image from Gallery and add to `Panel`

Comment: You can upvote and check my answer is right for future visitor.